# Accessing Form Elements in a view from a different Controller

Tags: javascript, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

Trying to update the label text in a view from my main controller.

I have 1 controller: index.js
Then i have 2 views: index.xml (for iOS) and android_index.xml (for android).

In the view that is linked to the controller I can access form elements like this in my index.js file

```
$.formLabel.text = "updated text"
```

but the other view, I store the controller in a variable like. This view is basically an orphan because it doesn't have a controller, I just right clicked and created a new view without a controller.

```
var win=Alloy.createController('android_index').getView();
```

and I can't seem to access the form elements in my index.js with:

```
win.formLabel.text = "updated text"
```

when I try it says it is undefined

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getView()` method return the first top-level view of your controller : https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Alloy.Controller-method-getView

If you want access to a child view you can do this :

```
var win=Alloy.createController('android_index'); //reference to your controller
win.formLabel.text = "updated text";
```

or this works too :

```
win.getView('formLabel').text = "updated text";
```

Comment: these didn't work for me. I got this error: 

uncaught type error: object #<Window> has no method ‘getView’

1 thing I'm not sure if i explained well. There is only 1 controller (index.js) and 2 views (index.xml, android_index.xm). The android_xml view is an orphan of sorts because it doesn't have a controller assigned to it like index.js does (index.js --> index.xml) (no controller --> android_index.xml). basically I just use: win.add(userLabel); to add things to the android view and then open it using win.open()

Comment: if android_xml view doesn't have a controller can I not access the lblUsername label in the android_xml view?

Comment: @MikeKellogg are you sure you changed your code to call `Alloy.createController('android_index').formLabel` and not `Alloy.createController('android_index').getView().formLabel`? Because that is what the error you get seems to indicate.

Comment: @Fokke-Appcelerator no I'm not sure hehe :). I will go back and try this on a copy of my project. What I ended up doing was creating a new controller that is connected to the view (aindex.js and aindex.xml) and making a method changeUsername. This function is exported so that index can call it and pass a string value into it as the new text for the label.

Comment: so basically I would do something like this?

var win=Alloy.createController('android_index');

win.formLabel.text = 'new text';

Comment: Yes, exactly ! win represent your controller. If you don't specified a view id, it return an instance of the named controller. Then, you can access to a specified view by win.[the view id]

Comment: @Fokke-Appcelerator while these 2 options that you two gave me did not throw errors, they failed to update the label with the new text. the label's name is lblUsername and it exists in the android_index.xml view and I am attempting to call these changes from index.js controller (index.js presumably cannot see the form elements in android_index.xml?). 
code:
`Alloy.createController('android_index').lblUsername.text = theUsername;`

where "theUsername" has a username stored from a rest call, the rest call works the label text doesn't update

Comment: why am I calling 'createController' on a view (android_index.xml)? don't mean to badger you guys, just need to understand the concepts behind this for the future. in my current solution this works and I have a second controller for android side of the app which I can call from my iOS controller to update form elements, this is probably better design

Comment: If you do `console.log(theUsername)` before you set `lblUsername.text` does it show the right value? Because that definitely should work. Any XML element that you give an ID becomes a property of the controller.

Comment: @Fokke-Appcelerator, yes it stores the right value for the username

Comment: Could you share your (XML+TSS) definition of `lblUsername` ?

Comment: @Fokke-Appcelerator, sorry I've wiped out that code since. This issue is resolved now though. Most of my problems were probably due to poor practices and ignorance :P

Comment: Good ;) Maybe you can accept this answer so that the question shows as answered.